# Marital status determinants

Tags: reference-request, regression, probability

I am looking for the researches that have studied **factors influencing marital status probability**. I need them for **citation purposes**. After looking for a long time I have not found anything. So I need something like **probit/logit regression on marriage status probability** and so on. Any researches of these kind **published in scientific journals** are welcome.

Will be very greatful for help!

Comment: I frankly can't tell what you're asking for.